# Is there a way to prevent catch from stopping my java app?

Tags: java, try-catch

I'm working on a little game in Java and I'm adding saves. I created a class that handles the loading of my Saves file and the saving of this file (I serialize a class). I added code to my save button and I want it tell the user when the game wasn't saved successfully, but the game should still keep going. It's just gonna say something like: "Your game didn't save." Here is the code I use:

For my button

```
gameView.getSaveButton().addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        //
        savesManager.getSaves().time=nbSecondes;
        try {
            savesManager.saveGame();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            gameView.setLevelLabelText("A problem occured. Your game wasn't saved!");
        }
        //Deactivate the save button
        gameView.getSaveButton().setEnabled(false);
    }
});
```

And the other code in my app that stops my app when it catches an exception:

```
 try(FileReader reader = new FileReader("app.properties"))
 {  
     ....
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: What's your question? That is, what went wrong?

Comment: I don't understand it either. The code looks like it would do what you're wanting.

Comment: Can you please paste the error you are getting . The code looks fine and will not stop executing if an exception occours

Comment: The truth is I don't get an error BUT, I have extremely similare code in my app and I tried with that other code, and in this case, it stop my app when it catch en exception. SO I logicly conluded that catch automatically stop the app, was I wrong?

Comment: A catch should not automatically stop your app.  My guess is that your other app was throwing an unhandled Exception, but without seeing the code, that's just a guess.

Comment: The edit is helpful, but the stack-trace would be even more so. (Also, it appears this is unrelated to the first piece of code you posted.)

Comment: I guess that my question wasn't ciorrectly formulated. What I meant to ask was, is catch suppos to automatically stop my app? I don't want it to stop my app in the case of the first block of code I posted. Will it actually stop it, or it will still execute the rest of my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going off the comments, esp. the OP's third one:

> What I meant to ask was, is `catch` suppose to automatically stop my app?

The answer is No. Program execution does not stop in a `catch` block. It continues on.